# Laravel transaction and loading relation after results in an empty relation

Tags: mysql, laravel

for simplicity let's asume I have two models Invoice and InvoiceLine. Invoice has a hasMany relation to InvoiceLines named lines(). Assume aswell the following chunk of code:

```
<?php

//...

class GenerateInvoicesService
{

    public function generateInvoices()
    {

        //...

        DB::beginTransaction();
        
        try {
            $invoice = Invoice::create([
                //...
            ]);

            foreach ($invoiceLines as $invoiceLine) {
                InvoiceLine::create([
                    'invoice_id' => $invoice->id,
                    //...
                ]);
            }

            DB::commit();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Error generating invoice or invoice lines');

            DB::rollBack();

            return false;
        }

        $lines = $invoice->lines;

        if ($lines->isEmpty()) {
            Log::error('No invoice lines');
            //...
        }

        //...

    }

//...
```

The BD is MariaDB 10.10.2 and the table invoices and invoice_lines are both InnoDB and one Invoice can have hundreds of InvoiceLines.

I expect lines to be filled with corresponding InvoiceLine models but in some cases, the returned collection is empty and the log is generated, for example generating like 300 Invoices only 7 have no lines when it should. By the way, the execution never throws exception.

The thing is if after executing the function of the service I go to de DB and check if the invoice has lines or not they always have lines and after executing the function if in another part of the code I try to load the relation the InvoiceLines apear in the collection.

Anyone have some idea about what are happening?

Answer (score 0):

`create` only throws an exception when there is a structure error such as the lack of a column in the database. If everything is correct and the same could not save just return a `false`.

You can use `createMany()` to make your code easier to read. [Check the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships)

```
public function generateInvoices()
{
    DB::beginTransaction();

    try {
        $invoice = Invoice::create([
            //...
        ]);
        if (!$invoice) {
            Log::error('Error generating invoice or invoice lines');
            DB::rollBack();
            return false;
        }
        $invoice->lines()->createMany($array_with_all_lines);

        DB::commit();

        $lines = $invoice->lines;

        if ($lines->isEmpty()) {
            Log::error('No invoice lines');
            //...
        }
    } catch (QueryException $e) {
        Log::error('db structure error');
        return false;
    }


    //...
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your quick response, but you are not answering what I just asked. My question is why $invoice->lines is empty

Comment: Are you using the `hasMany` relation?

Comment: yes! i'm using hasmany the thing is that when i run the function sometimes the relation is empty after the DB::commit(). Could be something related to data not ready in the DB when $invoice->lines is called?

Comment: I don't think so, theoretically your `DB::commit()` already guarantees that the data is in the base. Is it just sometimes it happens? try to look in the bank if in this specific case the data is there in the bank. Try putting a  `dump()` in the `create` to see at what point it is failing too, or if you have an xDebug it would be more interesting.

Comment: Ty for taking your time to respond Vitor. Nothing works and i feel that is because there is some delay between DB commit and data ready into de DB dunno why. I will do further investigation.